# How to create a Domino webuser session without knowing the user's password?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

In my XPages application, I want to programmatically create a session for a webuser and return a SessionId and DomAuthSessId as cookies to the browser.

As far as I know, the person documents for webusers only contain a hash of the HTTPPassword and this hash cannot be used for session creation.

Is there a way to create a session without knowing the user's password? For example, by signing the application with an admin id and then use sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess or something like this...

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: I want to implement single-sign-on (SSO) for users coming from another (non-domino/non-xpages) web application. If the user has successfully been authenticated in that application (oauth2) I can use the accesstoken to get his/her mail address and use it to automatically create a session for that user on the Domino server my XPages application runs on.

Answer (score 2):

You might not want to do this. If you need access to protected resources you can use the http client libraries on Domino and proxy the request. Or use sessionAsSigner to collect the information and return it.

However if you have to:
- the OpenNTF Domino API has a method to create a user session based on name only.
- sessionAsSigner gives you the signer's session

You then can use session.getSessionToken() to get the token. Neither method will get you access to encrypted content

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As soon as I have time to test if your approach works I will report back here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have an external system that is validating the user and do a autologin perhaps this [OpenNTF.org](http://www.openntf.org) xsnippet will help you.
Because with this you can create a login token for the user.
https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=ltpatoken-generator-for-multi-server-sso-configurations

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As soon as I have time to test if your approach works I will report back here.

Answer (score 2):

Years ago, the guys at nil.com wrote a blog post about this, and included a package that helps you work with LTPA tokens. The original blog post has since gone offline, but I'll include their code below - full credit to the guys at Nil of course.

The package lets you do the following in your xpage:

```
var ltpaSecret=LtpaLibrary.getLtpaSecret(names,siteName);
var token=LtpaLibrary.createLtpaToken(username, ltpaSecret.tokenExpiration,ltpaSecret.ltpaSecret);
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "LtpaToken=" + token + "; domain="+ltpaSecret.tokenDomain+"; path=/; HttpOnly; secure");
```

What this does is:

1. Get ltpa token secret for a specified internet site in a specified Domino directory
2. Create a new ltpatoken for the user and use the secret to sign it and set the expiry
3. Return the new ltpatoken to the browser as a cookie

Needless to say - you'll want to be very careful with this and make absolutely sure that nobody can abuse it. One way could be to put this into a dedicated NSF that only the server and one user have access to - the user being a service account for the SSO system to use. Even server admins shouldn't access the NSF normally.

The SSO system would call your xpage, pass it the username, take the returned cookie and serve this up to the user, before redirecting them into the application they were requesting access to.

The original package from nil.com:

```
package com.nil.ltpa;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Vector;

import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.Item;
import lotus.domino.NotesError;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.View;

import com.nil.exception.Base64DecodeException;
import com.nil.helpers.HttpUtils;

public class LtpaLibrary {

private static final byte[]    ltpaTokenVersion        = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
private static final int        dateStringLength        = 8;
private static final String    dateStringFiller        = "00000000";
private static final int        creationDatePosition    = ltpaTokenVersion.length;
private static final int        expirationDatePosition    = creationDatePosition + dateStringLength;
private static final int        preUserDataLength        = ltpaTokenVersion.length + dateStringLength + dateStringLength;
private static final int        hashLength            = 20;

/** This method parses the LtpaToken cookie received from the web browser and returns the information in the <tt>TokenData</tt>
 * class.
 * @param ltpaToken - the cookie (base64 encoded).
 * @param ltpaSecretStr - the contents of the <tt>LTPA_DominoSecret</tt> field from the SSO configuration document.
 * @return The contents of the cookie. If the cookie is invalid (the hash - or some other - test fails), this method returns
 * <tt>null</tt>.
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
 * @throws Base64DecodeException
 */
public static TokenData parseLtpaToken( String ltpaToken, String ltpaSecretStr ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        Base64DecodeException {
    byte[] data = HttpUtils.base64Decode( ltpaToken );

    int variableLength = data.length - hashLength;
    /* Compare to 20 to since variableLength must be at least (preUserDataLength + 1) [21] character long:
     * Token version: 4 bytes
     * Token creation: 8 bytes
     * Token expiration: 8 bytes
     * User name: variable length > 0
     */
    if( variableLength <= preUserDataLength ) return null;

    byte[] ltpaSecret = HttpUtils.base64Decode( ltpaSecretStr );

    if( !validateSHA( data, variableLength, ltpaSecret ) ) return null;

    if( !compareBytes( data, 0, ltpaTokenVersion, 0, ltpaTokenVersion.length ) ) return null;

    TokenData ret = new TokenData();
    ret.tokenCreated.setTimeInMillis( (long)Integer.parseInt( getString( data, creationDatePosition, dateStringLength ), 16 ) * 1000 );
    ret.tokenExpiration
            .setTimeInMillis( (long)Integer.parseInt( getString( data, expirationDatePosition, dateStringLength ), 16 ) * 1000 );

    byte[] nameBuffer = new byte[ data.length - ( preUserDataLength + hashLength ) ];
    System.arraycopy( data, preUserDataLength, nameBuffer, 0, variableLength - preUserDataLength );
    ret.username = new String( nameBuffer );

    return ret;
}

private static boolean validateSHA( byte[] ltpaTokenData, int variableLength, byte[] ltpaSecret ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-1" );

    byte[] digestData = new byte[ variableLength + ltpaSecret.length ];

    System.arraycopy( ltpaTokenData, 0, digestData, 0, variableLength );
    System.arraycopy( ltpaSecret, 0, digestData, variableLength, ltpaSecret.length );

    byte[] digest = sha1.digest( digestData );

    if( digest.length > ltpaTokenData.length - variableLength ) return false;

    int bytesToCompare = ( digest.length <= ltpaTokenData.length - variableLength ) ? digest.length : ltpaTokenData.length
            - variableLength;

    return compareBytes( digest, 0, ltpaTokenData, variableLength, bytesToCompare );
}

private static boolean compareBytes( byte[] b1, int offset1, byte[] b2, int offset2, int len ) {
    if( len < 0 ) return false;
    // offset must be positive, and the compare chunk must be contained the buffer
    if( ( offset1 < 0 ) || ( offset1 + len > b1.length ) ) return false;
    if( ( offset2 < 0 ) || ( offset2 + len > b2.length ) ) return false;

    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        if( b1[ offset1 + i ] != b2[ offset2 + i ] ) return false;

    return true;
}

/** Convert bytes from the buffer into a String.
 * @param buffer - the buffer to take the bytes from.
 * @param offset - the offset in the buffer to start at.
 * @param len - the number of bytes to convert into a String.
 * @return - A String representation of specified bytes.
 */
private static String getString( byte[] buffer, int offset, int len ) {
    if( len < 0 ) return "";
    if( ( offset + len ) > buffer.length ) return "";

    byte[] str = new byte[ len ];
    System.arraycopy( buffer, offset, str, 0, len );
    return new String( str );
}

/** Create a valid LTPA token for the specified user. The creation time is <tt>now</tt>.
 * @param username - the user to create the LTPA token for.
 * @param durationMinutes - the duration of the token validity in minutes.
 * @param ltpaSecretStr - the LTPA Domino Secret to use to create the token.
 * @return - base64 encoded LTPA token, ready for the cookie.
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
 * @throws Base64DecodeException
 */
public static String createLtpaToken( String username, int durationMinutes, String ltpaSecretStr ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        Base64DecodeException {
    return createLtpaToken( username, new GregorianCalendar(), durationMinutes, ltpaSecretStr );
}

/** Create a valid LTPA token for the specified user.
 * @param username - the user to create the LTPA token for.
 * @param creationTime - the time the token becomes valid.
 * @param durationMinutes - the duration of the token validity in minutes.
 * @param ltpaSecretStr - the LTPA Domino Secret to use to create the token.
 * @return - base64 encoded LTPA token, ready for the cookie.
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
 * @throws Base64DecodeException
 */
public static String createLtpaToken( String username, GregorianCalendar creationTime, int durationMinutes, String ltpaSecretStr )
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, Base64DecodeException {
    // create byte array buffers for both strings
    byte[] ltpaSecret = HttpUtils.base64Decode( ltpaSecretStr );
    byte[] usernameArray = username.getBytes();

    byte[] workingBuffer = new byte[ preUserDataLength + usernameArray.length + ltpaSecret.length ];

    // copy version into workingBuffer
    System.arraycopy( ltpaTokenVersion, 0, workingBuffer, 0, ltpaTokenVersion.length );

    GregorianCalendar expirationDate = (GregorianCalendar)creationTime.clone();
    expirationDate.add( Calendar.MINUTE, durationMinutes );

    // copy creation date into workingBuffer
    String hex = dateStringFiller + Integer.toHexString( (int)( creationTime.getTimeInMillis() / 1000 ) ).toUpperCase();
    System
            .arraycopy( hex.getBytes(), hex.getBytes().length - dateStringLength, workingBuffer, creationDatePosition,
                    dateStringLength );

    // copy expiration date into workingBuffer
    hex = dateStringFiller + Integer.toHexString( (int)( expirationDate.getTimeInMillis() / 1000 ) ).toUpperCase();
    System.arraycopy( hex.getBytes(), hex.getBytes().length - dateStringLength, workingBuffer, expirationDatePosition,
            dateStringLength );

    // copy user name into workingBuffer
    System.arraycopy( usernameArray, 0, workingBuffer, preUserDataLength, usernameArray.length );

    // copy the ltpaSecret into the workingBuffer
    System.arraycopy( ltpaSecret, 0, workingBuffer, preUserDataLength + usernameArray.length, ltpaSecret.length );

    byte[] hash = createHash( workingBuffer );

    // put the public data and the hash into the outputBuffer
    byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[ preUserDataLength + usernameArray.length + hashLength ];
    System.arraycopy( workingBuffer, 0, outputBuffer, 0, preUserDataLength + usernameArray.length );
    System.arraycopy( hash, 0, outputBuffer, preUserDataLength + usernameArray.length, hashLength );

    return HttpUtils.base64Encode( outputBuffer );
}

private static byte[] createHash( byte[] buffer ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA-1" );
    return sha1.digest( buffer );
}

private static boolean fieldContainsValue( Vector values, Item item ) throws NotesException {
    for( int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++ ) {
        if( item.containsValue( values.get( i ) ) ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Get the contents of the LTPA_Secret field of the correct SSO configuration document based on the Internet site host name.
 * @param names - the <strong>names.nsf</strong> database.
 * @param siteName - the Internet host name of the site to generate/verify Domino cookie for. 
 * @return A class containing LTPA data, <tt>null</tt> if no matching SSO configuration document was found.
 * @throws NotesException
 * @throws UnknownHostException
 */
public static LtpaData getLtpaSecret( Database names, String siteName ) throws NotesException {
    Vector searchValues = new Vector();
    searchValues.add( siteName );

    try {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName( siteName );
        searchValues.add( addr.getHostAddress() );
    } catch( UnknownHostException e ) {
        // do nothing
    }

    View internetSites = names.getView( "($InternetSites)" );
    String ssoQuery = "LtpaToken";

    Vector vRecycle = new Vector( internetSites.getEntryCount() );
    Document webSite = internetSites.getFirstDocument();
    while( webSite != null ) {
        vRecycle.add( webSite );
        if( webSite.getItemValueString( "Form" ).equalsIgnoreCase( "WebSite" )
                && webSite.getItemValueString( "Type" ).equalsIgnoreCase( "WebSite" ) ) {
            // The correct type of document
            if( fieldContainsValue( searchValues, webSite.getFirstItem( "ISiteAdrs" ) ) ) {
                ssoQuery = webSite.getItemValueString( "ISiteOrg" ) + ":" + webSite.getItemValueString( "HTTP_SSOCfg" );
                break;
            }
        }
        webSite = internetSites.getNextDocument( webSite );
    }
    internetSites.recycle( vRecycle ); // recycle all the collected documents
    internetSites.recycle();

    View ssoConfigs = names.getView( "($WebSSOConfigs)" );
    Document ssoConfigDoc = ssoConfigs.getDocumentByKey( ssoQuery );
    ssoConfigs.recycle();

    if( ssoConfigDoc == null )
        throw new NotesException( NotesError.NOTES_ERR_SSOCONFIG, "Site \"" + siteName + "\" SSO config document not found." );

    LtpaData ret = new LtpaData( ssoConfigDoc.getItemValueString( "LTPA_DominoSecret" ), ssoConfigDoc
            .getItemValueInteger( "LTPA_TokenExpiration" ), ssoConfigDoc.getItemValueString( "LTPA_TokenDomain" ) );

    ssoConfigDoc.recycle();

    return ret;
}
}







package com.nil.ltpa;

public class LtpaData {

public String    ltpaSecret;
public String    tokenDomain;
public int    tokenExpiration;

public LtpaData() {
    ltpaSecret = "";
    tokenDomain = "";
    tokenExpiration = 0;
}

public LtpaData( String ltpaSecret, int tokenExpiration, String tokenDomain ) {
    super();
    this.ltpaSecret = ltpaSecret;
    this.tokenExpiration = tokenExpiration;
    this.tokenDomain = tokenDomain;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public String toString() {
    return "LTPAData {Secret=" + ltpaSecret + ", expiration=" + tokenExpiration + ", domain=" + tokenDomain + "}";
}

}



package com.nil.ltpa;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.SimpleTimeZone;

public class TokenData {
public static final SimpleTimeZone    utcTimeZone    = new SimpleTimeZone( 0, "UTC" );

public String                    username;
public GregorianCalendar            tokenCreated;
public GregorianCalendar            tokenExpiration;

public TokenData() {
    username = "";
    tokenCreated = new GregorianCalendar( utcTimeZone );
    tokenCreated.setTimeInMillis( 0 );
    tokenExpiration = new GregorianCalendar( utcTimeZone );
    tokenExpiration.setTimeInMillis( 0 );
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    buf.append( "[ username:" ).append( username ).append( ", tokenCreated: " ).append( tokenCreated.getTime().toString() );
    buf.append( ", tokenExpiration: " ).append( tokenExpiration.getTime().toString() ).append( " ]" );

    return buf.toString();
}
}



package com.nil.helpers;

import java.util.Vector;

import com.nil.exception.Base64DecodeException;

public class HttpUtils {

private static final String    base64Chars    = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

public static final String base64Encode( byte[] bytes ) {
    if( bytes == null ) return null;

    StringBuffer ret = new StringBuffer();

    for( int sidx = 0, didx = 0; sidx < bytes.length; sidx += 3, didx += 4 ) {
        ret.append( base64Chars.charAt( ( bytes[ sidx ] >>> 2 ) & 077 ) );
        if( sidx + 1 < bytes.length ) {
            ret.append( base64Chars.charAt( ( bytes[ sidx + 1 ] >>> 4 ) & 017 | ( bytes[ sidx ] << 4 ) & 077 ) );
            if( sidx + 2 < bytes.length )
                ret.append( base64Chars.charAt( ( bytes[ sidx + 2 ] >>> 6 ) & 003 | ( bytes[ sidx + 1 ] << 2 ) & 077 ) );
            else
                ret.append( base64Chars.charAt( ( bytes[ sidx + 1 ] << 2 ) & 077 ) );
            if( sidx + 2 < bytes.length ) ret.append( base64Chars.charAt( bytes[ sidx + 2 ] & 077 ) );
        } else
            ret.append( base64Chars.charAt( ( bytes[ sidx ] << 4 ) & 077 ) );
    }

    int mod = ret.length() % 4;
    for( int i = 0; ( mod > 0 ) && ( i < 4 - mod ); i++ )
        ret.append( '=' );

    return ret.toString();
} // public static final String base64Encode( byte[] bytes )

public static final byte[] base64Decode( String data ) throws Base64DecodeException {
    if( data.length() == 0 ) return new byte[ 0 ];
    Vector dest = new Vector( data.length() );

    // ASCII printable to 0-63 conversion
    int prevBits = 0; // stores the bits left over from the previous step
    int modAdjust = 0; // stores the start of the current line.
    for( int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++ ) {
        char ch = data.charAt( i ); // get the character
        if( ch == '=' ) break; // is it the padding character, no check for correct position
        int mod = ( i - modAdjust ) % 4; // what is the index modulo 4 in the current line
        if( mod == 0 ) {
            // the line can only be broken on modulo 0 (e.g. 72, 76 character per line. MIME specifies 76 as max).
            if( ( ch == '\r' ) || ( ch == '\n' ) ) { // we handle the encoders that use '\n' only as well
                modAdjust = i + 1; // skip the [CR/]LF sequence. The new line probably starts at i + 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        // if we came to here, there was no special character
        int x = base64Chars.indexOf( ch ); // search for the character in the table
        if( x < 0 ) throw new Base64DecodeException(); // if the character was not found raise an exception
        switch( mod ) {
            case 0:
                prevBits = x << 2; // just store the bits and continue
                break;
            case 1:
                dest.add( new Byte( (byte)( prevBits | x >>> 4 ) ) ); // previous 6 bits OR 2 new ones
                prevBits = ( x & 017 ) << 4; // store 4 bits
                break;
            case 2:
                dest.add( new Byte( (byte)( prevBits | x >>> 2 ) ) ); // previous 4 bits OR 4 new ones
                prevBits = ( x & 003 ) << 6; // store 2 bits
                break;
            case 3:
                dest.add( new Byte( (byte)( prevBits | x ) ) ); // previous 2 bits OR 6 new ones
                break;
        }
    }

    byte[] ret = new byte[ dest.size() ]; // convert the Vector into an array
    for( int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++ )
        ret[ i ] = ( (Byte)dest.get( i ) ).byteValue();

    return ret;
}

public static final boolean isBase64Encoded( String sBase64 ) {
    int len = sBase64.length();
    if( len % 4 != 0 ) return false;
    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        char c = sBase64.charAt( i );
        if( ( c >= 'a' ) && ( c <= 'z' ) ) continue;
        if( ( c >= 'A' ) && ( c <= 'Z' ) ) continue;
        if( ( c >= '0' ) && ( c <= '9' ) ) continue;
        if( ( c == '+' ) || ( c == '/' ) || ( c == '=' ) ) continue;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}



package com.nil.exception;

public class Base64DecodeException extends Exception {
/**
 *
 */
private static final long    serialVersionUID    = -5600202677007235761L;

/**
 *
 */
public Base64DecodeException() {
    // Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @param argMessage
 */
public Base64DecodeException( String argMessage ) {
    super( argMessage );
}

/**
 * @param argCause
 */
public Base64DecodeException( Throwable argCause ) {
    super( argCause );
}

/**
 * @param argMessage
 * @param argCause
 */
public Base64DecodeException( String argMessage, Throwable argCause ) {
    super( argMessage, argCause );
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and the code. As soon as I have time to test if it works I will report back here.